# What is this long rectangle component from a Dyson BMS?

Tags: identification, components, bms

I found this long rectangle component marked "CD 18-19" on a Dyson BMS. I am wondering what it is, but didn't find any info online, and my component tester did not recognise it.
Here is a picture of the desoldered component :

[image]

And for context, here's a picture of the typical Dyson BMS, on which you see the component on the lower extremity :

[image: Dyson BMS]

And from the side:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: looks like a reed switch ... could also be an antenna

Comment: Based on its position I would guess that it is a reed switch.  In use, is that end of the board placed near a magnet?  If so, that could confirm my guess.

Comment: Yes it's a reed switch. https://github.com/tinfever/FU-Dyson-BMS